# Build a Shared Project Visual Studio 2105?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Visual Studio 2015 Community

How do you build a Shared Project Visual Studio 2105?

I have tried creating a Shared Project and adding one .cs file, when I try and Build it I get ‘Run Code Analysis on Solution Alt+F11’ as a drop down.  There is nothing for Build like there is when you create a normal Project.

So I added the Shared Project to my main Project and Build from there. The main Project builds without any Errors and then try and add a Reference to the Shared Project but get the error message:

A reference to .........could not be added.  Please make sure the file is accessible, and the at its is a valid assembly for COM component.

I must be missing a very simple step.

Any tips would be helpful.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

1. It looks like you don't need to build the shared project.
2. When adding a reference to the a Shared Project (right click on References, Add Reference, select Shared Projects(I kept choosing Projects) and browse to your Shared Project.